# QThread's subclassing throws undefined refenrence error when start() method is called

Tags: multithreading, qt

I've the following code setup-

in file **testthread.h**

```
class test_thread :public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void start();
};
```

In cpp file

```
test_thread *t = new test_thread;
t->start();
```

When executing the above codes, I get the error-

`error: undefined reference to test_thread::start()`

I don't understand what goes wrong. Calling a QThread object's start() method doesn't show any errors but when I subclass QThread, it does. Any help or advice on this would be awesome!

Thanks :)

Comment: there is no class called worker in the code you showed, you should post it. Also, I assume the method has been implemented and linked correctly?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro -Hi, it should be test_thread::start(). Sorry for that blunder. I was implementing it on worker class (subclassing from QThread) but after finding the error, I tested it for a simpler class test_thread that inherits from QThread. Anyways I've corrected it. What do you mean by implemented and linked correctly?

Comment: Means there is a void test_thread::start() on your cpp file with the correct code, and that file is compiled and linked into the main executable. Not doing that would generate that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `void start();` from your header file. If there is `start` implementation in the source file, you need to remove it too. `start` method is not supposed to be reimplemented.

You may want to reimplement `run` virtual method. If so, add `void run()` to the header and add appropriate `test_thread::run() { ... }` implementation in the source file.

Note that `QThread` should not be subclassed in most cases.

Comment: Hi. Yes I did that and it's working fine now. I've also implemented the run() method. Please elaborate on why `QThread` shouldn't be sublassed in most cases.

Comment: See this page: [Subclassing no longer recommended way of using QThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/5/8/view)

Comment: Subclassing is still needed in some cases though, the whole discussion is based on these 3 links:
Why subclassing is wrong (in most cases) http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/ 
Why subclassing is good (in some cases) http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html
When to use threading (types): http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html